# Use the Taylor Polynomial of order $3$ for $f(x)=\sin x$ about $x=0$ and its remainder term to prove that: $x-(x^3/6)<\sin x$, for $0<x<\pi$

Tags: calculus

This is a two part question, and I need help with the 2nd part.

For this 1st question, I found the remainder term and showed that for $0 < c < \pi$, the remainder term is $> 0$, therefore, the inequality holds true. Is this sufficient proof?

The 2nd part of the question asks:

Show that the inequality in part (1) holds for all real positive x and deduce that:

$$x-\frac{x^3}{6} < \sin x < x$$

for all real positive $x$.

Can someone help me with this second part?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that $x-x^3/3$ is decrasing. $x$ is tangent to the sine at $x=0$, and the sine is concave in $(0,\pi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the derivatives. You can do something like this:

If we have that $f'(x)>0$ for every $x>a$, then $\int_a^x\!f'(t)\,dt>0$ which implies $f(x)>f(a)$ for every $x>a$. A similar result holds for $f'(x)<0$.

For $\sin(x)<x$ you clearly only need to worry about $x\in(0,1]$, and applying this to $x-\sin x$ will take care of that nicely. For the other inequality, you've already taken care of the hard part, now just apply this approach with $a=3$, for instance.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks Michael. A great help.

Comment: @mathstudent No problem. Also your approach to the first part is sufficient proof.